# I have this trigonometric expression to prove

Tags: trigonometry

I have tried to substitute $\tan (x)$ and $\cot (x)$ with sine and cosine and it got really messy

$$1-\frac{\sin^2x}{1+\cot(x)}-\frac{\cos^2x}{1+\tan x}=?$$

**a)** $1$

**b)** $\sin^2x$

**c)** $\sin (x)+\cos (x)$

**d)** $\sin (x)\cdot \cos (x)$

Comment: Have you at least calculated some values so you know which of $(a, b, c, d)$ to prove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write this as : here I put $$\cot x= \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$$ and $$\tan x= \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$

$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x-\frac{\sin^3x}{\sin x+\cos x}-\frac{\cos^3x}{\sin x+\cos x}$$

Now take take the $\operatorname{lcm}$ and you'll get something like this:

$$\frac {\sin^3x+\cos^3x+ \sin x\cos^2x+\cos x \sin^2x-\sin^3x-\cos^3x}{\sin x+\cos x}$$
then
$$\frac{\sin x\cos x(\sin x+\cos x)}{\sin x +\cos x}$$
hence final asnwer is

d) $\sin x.\cos x$

Comment: ItiShree: Tip for formatting your posts.  When it comes to trig functions, you can properly format the function using, for example `\cos x , \sin x, \tan x' etc. (simply using a backward slash immediately prior to the trig function you'd like to use.)

Comment: It is me who should thank you kind person for you detailed explanation

Comment: @amWhy Thanks , I'm new so working on it.

Comment: @L.B No need to thank, it's my pleasure helping you.

Comment: @amWhy i appreciate it, thank you

Comment: When I was new here, I remember how much I learned (wrt formatting) given the help of other users.  You'll catch on. It's sort of a trial and error kind of thing, but you're doing really good so far!

Comment: @amWhy Thanks this sites got loads of great users, only one person bashed me for this which is far lower than other sites. And I'm loving it, everyone's awesome here.

Answer (score 2):

note that $$\cot(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$ and $$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$$ the result is $$\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
we have $$\frac{(1+\cot(x))(1+\tan(x))-\sin^2(x)(1+\tan(x))-\cos^2(x)(1+\cot(x))}{(1+\cot(x))(1+\tan(x))}$$
multiplying out and we otain
$$\frac{1+\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}+\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}-\frac{\sin^3(x)}{\cos(x)}-\frac{\cos(x)^3}{\sin(x)}}{(1+\cot(x))(1+\tan(x))}$$
and this is
$$\frac{1+\frac{\cos(x)(1-\cos^2(x))}{\sin(x)}+\frac{\sin(x)(1-\sin^2(x))}{\cos(x)}}{(1+\cot(x))(1+\tan(x))}$$
we will work further:
$$\frac{1+2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{2+\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}+\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}}$$
and this is $$\frac{(1+2\sin(x)\cos(x))\sin(x)\cos(x)}{2\sin(x)\cos(x)+1}=\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

Comment: why the $-2$, what is wrong with my result?

Comment: I have no issues with your result, I have issues with your argument. In it's current state you are missing steps to show how you went from substituting $\cot$/$\tan$ for their quotients to the final result.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail how you came to this result because tan(x)=sine/cosine and cotx= cos/sin i know that already and tried that, there is something i missed and i would like to know

Comment: ok i will insert steps,ok?

Comment: That would be great!

Comment: i hope i have made no typos